# Should small amounts of data be stored in a database in Android?

Tags: android, database

If I was creating an Android app that for example stored alarm clock times and information, would it be best to put that information in a database, write to file, or user preferences. I would only access that data to create the list of alarms and when editing a specific alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the overhead of creating a database is overkill for this.  Writing to a file, well, it depends, but it seems like this would be a good way to do it. I'm assuming that you don't know how many of them there will be.  If it's a fixed small number, you could use preferences.

I tend to pick the easiest way that doesn't rely on anything else working correctly :)